# Using rng(Random Number Generator) for a specific function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, loops, random

Suppose that we have two m-files :

First one is a function :

```
function XX = ofx()

for i=1:2
    aa = randperm(5)
end

end
```

Second one :

```
rng(0);
for i=1:2
   xx = randperm(3)
end

ofx();
```

You can see that when we run second code again and again the outputs is the same. Why we have these same outputs in both `randperm`? I only want same random generator for `xx` random numbers not `ofx` function. How can i do that? How can i only use `rng` for a specific function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the function.  The problem is that you want a repeatable sequence of numbers for some uses of the RNG, and non-repeating for other uses.  To do this, you need to carefully control the state of the RNG.  I would reverse the way you think about them, and have your repeatable case save, then restore the state.

```
rng_state = rng(0);     % Save (pseudo-) random state of RNG, then seed with known value
for i=1:2
    xx = randperm(3);
end
rng(rng_state);         % Restore saved state so other RNG calls work as expected

ofx();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can we reset `rng` to `default` values likes we didn't use it? Can we return `MATLAB` random generator to `default` not previous condition `rng_state`?

Comment: Running `help rng` shows this possibility: `rng('default')`.  You could also use `rng('shuffle')` to "re-randomize" the rng.